What do the coefficients on correlated variables mean?
The coefficients on uncorrelated variables denote the degree to which the unique information in them influences the final variable. But what do the coefficients on correlated variables mean - who is how much of a “tug-of-war”? (no math, please)

Seems you are asking about multicollinearity - when independent features in a linear regression model are highly correlated with each other.
Let's imagine that we want to buy a used car. Most likely, the mileage (x1) will strongly correlate with the age of the car (x2): the older the car, the more km it has probably traveled, and vice versa.
The linear regression model looks like this:
F(x) = w0 + w1x1 + w2x2, where w are the weights, the "contribution" of each feature x to the target variable.
If the mileage coef (w1) is big, it may mean that used cars with lower mileage have higher prices, and the age of the car coef (w2) may be also high. As a result, it is difficult to understand what unique information each feature brings. It may be difficult to explain their individual effects (uncertainty), and it's leading to problems such as multicollinearity. With no math - multicollinearity is very bad :-)
Usually such features are removed or transformed (for example, one feature can be made - milage per year for example)

Welcome to SO; kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines.

When two variables in a regression are correlated, it complicates the interpretation of the coefficients. Normally, a coefficient tells you how much the dependent variable is expected to change for a one-unit increase in the independent variable, holding everything else constant. But when two variables are highly correlated, this "holding everything else constant" part gets tricky.
Here’s what happens:

The standard errors of the coefficients get larger, making them less precise.
The coefficients themselves can become unstable, meaning they can change a lot with even slight changes in the data.
The signs or values of the coefficients can be misleading, suggesting a relationship that isn’t really there.

This doesn’t mean the regression is useless, but you should be careful when interpreting the results if your variables are correlated. You might need to drop one of the correlated variables or combine them to avoid these issues.

Please do not answer obviously off-topic questions, they have not anything to do with programming.

Welcome to SO; kindly refrain from answering off-topic questions, as advised in the community guidelines.
